# ¿Cómo leer celdas de excel, como números y no caracteres con php?

Tags: php, mysqli, excel

¡Buen día!
Lo que pasa que cuando cargo datos desde Excel me da error al cargar decimales, por ejemplo: **precio compra**

```
$precioCompra =$conexion->real_escape_string( $objPHPExcel               
->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G'.$i)->getCalculatedValue());
```

Por ejemplo para leer una celda, uso ***real_escape_string*** para evitar la inserción de datos a través del Excel, lo que pasa que cuando son números, al insertarlos da error en **SQL**.

> error al ACTUALIZAR datosIncorrect decimal value: '5761,26' for column
>   'precioComp' at row 4

lo curioso que el dato lleva "." y no ",": Asi ***5761.26***
 ¿Hay una sentencia para eso? ¿Para que solo lea números decimales?

Aquí esta lo que me sale después de poner el código

```
echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);  // imprimir el locale actual
var_dump(localeconv());     // imprimir la configuración de numeros y monedas actual
die();                      // terminar el script (asi vemos por pantalla)
```

```html
Spanish_Spain.1252

C:\wamp\www\proyectos LUCES\datosAdmin\cargar_archivo.php:93:
array (size=18)
  'decimal_point' => string ',' (length=1)
  'thousands_sep' => string '.' (length=1)
  'int_curr_symbol' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
  'currency_symbol' => string '�' (length=1)
  'mon_decimal_point' => string ',' (length=1)
  'mon_thousands_sep' => string '.' (length=1)
  'positive_sign' => string '' (length=0)
  'negative_sign' => string '-' (length=1)
  'int_frac_digits' => int 2
  'frac_digits' => int 2
  'p_cs_precedes' => int 0
  'p_sep_by_space' => int 1
  'n_cs_precedes' => int 0
  'n_sep_by_space' => int 1
  'p_sign_posn' => int 1
  'n_sign_posn' => int 1
  'grouping' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 3
  'mon_grouping' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 3
```

Comment: hay un conflicto de `locales` fijate que te dice un `var_dump(localeconv());` seguramente tengas que setear el [locale con `setlocale();`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: Disculpa, no sé cómo usar ***Var_dump(localecon())***. Cómo lo aplicó¿?

Comment: en cualquier parte del script (justo antes de esa línea que mostras) `var_dump(localeconv());die();` eso te muestra que separadores de decimales y miles está usando php y termina el script

Comment: me sale esto:
         C:\wamp\www\proyectos LUCES\datosAdmin\cargar_archivo.php:92:
array (size=18)
  'decimal_point' => string ',' (length=1)
  'thousands_sep' => string '.' (length=1)
  'int_curr_symbol' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
  'currency_symbol' => string '�' (length=1)
  'mon_decimal_point' => string ',' (length=1)
  'mon_thousands_sep' => string '.' (length=1)
  'positive_sign' => string '' (length=0)

Comment: 'negative_sign' => string '-' (length=1)
  'int_frac_digits' => int 2
  'frac_digits' => int 2
  'p_cs_precedes' => int 0
  'p_sep_by_space' => int 1
  'n_cs_precedes' => int 0
  'n_sep_by_space' => int 1
  'p_sign_posn' => int 1
  'n_sign_posn' => int 1
  'grouping' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 3
  'mon_grouping' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 3

Comment: podes editar la pregunta y agregar esa info, ademas podes agregar la salida de `echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);` (ponerlo antes del var_dump). a partir de ahi vemos que locale te conviene usar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, el resultado del `echo` y el `var_dump` indican que efectivamente el `locale` de PHP está puesto a español de España con la codificación de caracteres 1252 (Windows Europa Occidental).

La solución mas simple y directa es (elimina el echo y el vardump) agregar al inicio del script un [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.setlocale.php):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

Esto hace que el separador de decimales sea `.` y el de miles `,`. Pueden surgir algunas otras cuestiones de caracteres y traducciones según la codificación.

Así que algo menos global puede ser:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');
```

Esto sólo afectaría a los números y deja las otras cosas como están (español para las fechas, euro para moneda, 1252 como codificación de caracteres).

Comment: gracias, me funciono con ***setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');***

Comment: es la opción menos intrusiva, la otra cambia muchas cosas, fijate en la página del manual que hay varias opciones. si en la importación de textos aparecen caracteres extraños ahi tal vez tengas que cambiar la codificación de caracteres (pero para eso ya hay otras preguntas y respuestas que ayudan)