# porque al cambiar un valor de entero a con decimal me sale error?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

buen dia

trabajando con php, estoy haciendo un carrito de compras. 
todo estaba bien hasta que me di cuenta que no me guarda valores con decimales, puros enteros en tablas como de precios o totales, etc.

mis tablas las tenia en tipo decimal, luego las cambie a double y no me afecto en nada.
solo que cuando el dato tiene decimales me manda este error:

`total Compra1 :16073
total desc 1607,3
total Compra:14465,7
error al insertar datos de compra Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

imprimi los valores que tengo para ver las cuentas. en ese ejemplo si no le quito el descuento, lo guarda sin errores

esta es mi tabla
[image: tabla]

y este es el codigo de insertar

```html
echo '<br>total Compra1 :'.$totalCompra.'<br>';
$totalDescuento=$totalCompra*($descuentoStatus/100);
echo 'total desc '.$totalDescuento;
$totalCompra= $totalCompra-$totalDescuento;
   echo '<br>total Compra:'.$totalCompra.'<br>';
   //$totalCompra=$totalCompra+$gastosEnvio;
 mysqli_query( $conexion, "INSERT INTO compras (numeroCompra, idDistr, nomDistr, fechaCompra, formaPago, articulos, totalCompra, descuento, statusCompra) VALUES ('$numeroCompra','$IDUSUARIO','$nomUsuario', ' $fecha', '$formaPago', '$articulosTotal', $totalCompra, '$descuentoStatus', '$statusCompra')" )or die( "error al insertar datos de compra " . mysqli_error( $conexion ) );
```

Para que lo inserte bien. Le agregué este código para dar formato con el punto ***.***  Pero cómo le puedo hacer para que el formato se aplique para todas la páginas. O hago variable por variable

```
   number_format($número, 2, '.', '');
```

// 1234.56

Comment: Los double los tienes double(100, 0) Van a tomar hasta 100 valores antes del decimal, y 0 valores luego del decimal.

Comment: ya lo cambie ha   descuento  double(10,2)
  costoEnvio  double(15,2)
 totalCompra  double(22,2), y sigue el error, o como seria?

Comment: estás mandando los decimales con comas?

Comment: Por lo que veo si. Si lo manda con comas

Comment: puede que tengas un problema de `Locale` fijate esta respuesta si te soluciona https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/189348/81450 (agregar un `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');`)

Comment: Listo. Fue eso gracias. No me aparece para darte cómo respuesta buena. Solo esto ∆

Comment: buenísimo que lo solucionaste, supongo que habría que redactar una pregunta/respuesta canónica para los temas de localización en php. No da para marcar como duplicado (según parece había un tema de comillas también) pero queda el registro en los enlazados. =)

Comment: Se recomienda usar `DECIMAL` en lugar de `DOUBLE` para datos en los que se van a guardar precios, porque `double` es más susceptible de errores en los cálculos. [Aquí puedes ver una explicación detallada con información tomada de la documentación de MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130611/29967)

Comment: muchas gracias por informacion, lo voy a cambiar. y lo tomo en cuenta para la siguiente

Answer (score 1):

lo unico que veo diferente es que el campo `totalCompra` esta sin comillas, por ende ha de llegar algo como 11,2 y al query interpretar esa `,` cree que son dos parametros diferentes, por ende ponlos entre comllias o asegurate que llegue el dato con el `.` para que sea bien recibido, intenta asi:

```
mysqli_query( $conexion, "INSERT INTO compras 
(numeroCompra, idDistr, nomDistr, fechaCompra, formaPago, articulos, totalCompra, descuento, statusCompra) 
VALUES 
('$numeroCompra','$IDUSUARIO','$nomUsuario', '$fecha', '$formaPago', '$articulosTotal', '$totalCompra', '$descuentoStatus', '$statusCompra')" 
)or die( "error al insertar datos de compra " . mysqli_error( $conexion ) );
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas como te fue!

Comment: Me lo manda aún con ***,*** y no con el ***.***. Cómo le cambio eso?

Comment: lo pusiste entre comillas ?